# Datatable function is not working when load table from another page via ajax post method

Tags: datatables

My datatable jquery is not working. When i am load table from another page via ajax post method. Please help me.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
// Call ajax
function getTable()
{
    $.post("datatable.php",
            {
            },
            function(data){
                /*alert(data);*/
                $("#showData").html(data);
            });

}
// Datatable function
//$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable();
//});
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working?  Are you getting an error message?  If you are, please edit your post to include the error message.

Comment: $('#example').DataTable();  not working. I am not getting any error message in console

Comment: Why do you have the `{ },` in your `$.post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable()` is executed *before* `$.post` is finished - initialise the dataTable inside the success handler as well :

```js
<script>
function getTable() {
    $.post("datatable.php", function(data){
        $("#showData").html(data);
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
}
getTable()
</script>
```